# What is the way to pass pre-populated values to Angular 2 reactive form input

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

import { User } from '../account.interface';
import { AF } from '../angularfire.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-account',
  templateUrl: './account.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./account.component.less']
})
export class AccountComponent implements OnInit {
  public error: any;
  user: FormGroup;
  onSubmit() {
    console.log(this.user.value, this.user.valid);
  }

  currentUserDetails = [];
  firstName: string = '';
  lastName: string = '';
  email: string = '';
  phone: string = '';
  bio: string = '';
  userID: string = '';

  constructor(private afService: AF) {
    // Get current user details and push to array.  This is due to input values overwriting ngModels.
    afService.getCurrentUserInfo().then(currentUserDetails => {
      let currentUser = [];
      currentUser.push(currentUserDetails);
      this.firstName = currentUser[0].firstName;
      this.lastName = currentUser[0].lastName;
      this.email = currentUser[0].email;
      this.phone = currentUser[0].phone;
      this.bio = currentUser[0].bio;
      this.userID = currentUser[0].userID;
    }).then(() => {

    })
  }

  // Update the user details with the form entry.
  // updateUserEntry(firstName, lastName, phone, bio) {
  //   this.afService.updateUserEntry(this.userID, firstName, lastName, phone, bio).then(() => {
  //     location.reload();
  //   }).catch((error) => {
  //     this.error = error;
  //     console.log("error");
  //   });
  // }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.user = new FormGroup({
      fname: new FormControl(this.firstName, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3), Validators.maxLength(24)]),
      lname: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3), Validators.maxLength(24)]),
      phone: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3), Validators.maxLength(24)]),
      bio: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5), Validators.maxLength(50)]),
    });
  }

}
```

I know it's probably a really simple fix, I'm just not seeing it.  I have my reactive `formControl`'s in my `ngOnInit` but I need to pass preset values into each input (which is `this.firstName`, `this.lastName`, etc.).  When the view loads, the inputs are empty.

I believe the values aren't showing up because the form is loading before the values are populated.  Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried using `pachValue` or `setValue`?

Comment: @yurzui Thank you, I didn't know about setValue and it works perfectly!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would be right. ngOnInit is already done before your getCurrentUserInfo is finished receiving data from your service. It is working asynchronously to avoid slowing down the application.

You either need to apply an observable to watch when your asynchronous request is done and the data is loaded or you can simply set your user new FormGroup inside of the "then" like this:

```
afService.getCurrentUserInfo().then(currentUserDetails => {
    let currentUser = [];
    currentUser.push(currentUserDetails);
    this.firstName = currentUser[0].firstName;
    this.lastName = currentUser[0].lastName;
    this.email = currentUser[0].email;
    this.phone = currentUser[0].phone;
    this.bio = currentUser[0].bio;
    this.userID = currentUser[0].userID;

    this.user = new FormGroup({
      fname: new FormControl(this.firstName, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3), Validators.maxLength(24)]),
      lname: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3), Validators.maxLength(24)]),
      phone: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3), Validators.maxLength(24)]),
      bio: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5), Validators.maxLength(50)]),
    });
})
```

Better yet, you can create a new method for reusability:

```
SetFormGroup() {
    this.user = new FormGroup({
      fname: new FormControl(this.firstName, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3), Validators.maxLength(24)]),
      lname: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3), Validators.maxLength(24)]),
      phone: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3), Validators.maxLength(24)]),
      bio: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5), Validators.maxLength(50)]),
    });
}
```

And call that method inside the "then".

Comment: This is not the issue to convert observables to promises

Answer (score 2):

Solved the issue using Angular 2's `setValue()`.  Example code solution:

```
this.user.setValue({fname: this.firstName, lname: this.lastName, phone: this.phone, bio: this.bio});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setValue()` if the control is already created or use it in constructor

```
new FormControl('your value',
```

I know that you can fix it some way because you know reactive form well but the value is pre-populated in *this* way.